# Unable to resolve relative path to another directory, then to securedlogin.php, on the same lvel

Tags: php

Hi I have tried all means to use relative to securedlogin.php in main.php

```
include_once 'secured/securedlogin.php';
```

1. ../secured/securedlogin.php
2. /secured/securedlogin.php
3. ../../securedlogin.php
4. secured/securedlogin.php

None of them works.

[image]

What should be the correct?

Please advise
Clement

Comment: secured/securedlogin.php

Comment: Thanks. It did not work. However It still worked with your tip after changing the codes.

Answer (score 2):

```
include_once __DIR__ . '/secured/securedlogin.php';
```

The `__DIR__` predefined constant always points to the directory current file is located. So using something similar to my advice would guarantee to always include what you want and not rely on current working directory.

Comment: @user1739825: then you've provided a wrong filesystem structure

Comment: I showed the picture clearly. Anyway I changed the codings. Now it worked after I followed the simple and straight forward example. Weird.

Comment: @user1739825: there is no chance the provided code doesn't include the file if the schema is correct :-)